# How to fit components with equal width horizontally?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, grid-system

I've two radio buttons. On the second radio button I want put 3 components and align the size width to fit on a unique line (row). They are a radio button and 2 select fields using Vuetify.

At the moment the components are on 3 rows, but I don't know how to put it into a unique row into 3 columns. I has followed the grid system from [Vuetify](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/grids/).

```
<v-flex xs12>
  <v-radio-group v-model="paymentType" column>
    <v-radio :label="getCurrentMonthText()"></v-radio>

    <v-container>
      <v-row no-gutters>
        <v-col cols="12" sm="4">
          <v-radio label="Outro mês"></v-radio>
        </v-col>
        <v-col cols="12" sm="4">
          <v-select label="Mês" :items="monthNames" v-model="monthSelected"></v-select>
        </v-col>
        <v-col cols="12" sm="4">
          <v-select label="Ano" :items="years" v-model="yearSelected"></v-select>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-container>
  </v-radio-group>
</v-flex>
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to have the "Outro Mes" radio button, the "Mes" selector, and the "Ano" selector all in the same row.

Your code is doing that right now for window sizes larger than "sm" in the vuetify grid system. When I run it on my machine, I get this:

[Window size larger than "sm"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SktH.png)

[Window size "sm"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddVrI.png)

If you want to have the radio button on the same row as the selects at all times, even when the window size is "sm", then you simply need to change each column to [cols="4"].

If I'm not understanding your question correctly, please leave a comment with clarification.